# Cannot special non-generic type AnyObject

Tags: swift

```
public protocol Subscriber : class {
}
public struct Subscription {
    private weak var subscriber:AnyObject<Subscriber>? = nil
}
```

Why can't I use `AnyObject` with a protocol for this var?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift doesn't allow combining a type and a protocol the way Objective-C does, although you can specify a combination of protocols. Since `AnyObject` is in fact a protocol, you can accomplish what you want to express above by writing:

```
public struct Subscription {
    private weak var subscriber:protocol<Subscriber, AnyObject>? = nil
}
```

This requires `subscriber` to conform to both the `Subscriber` and the `AnyObject` protocols.

In your case above, you actually don't need the `AnyObject` part since you made the `Subscriber` protocol a `class` protocol which essentially guarantees that any conforming type is also an `AnyObject`.  So you could just write:

```
public struct Subscription {
    private weak var subscriber:Subscriber? = nil
}
```

But the `protocol<Subscriber, AnyObject>` approach would allow your Subscriber protocol to not be restricted to only class types, while making that specific `subscriber` weak var restricted to class types that implement `Subscriber`.

Answer (score 2):

To refer to an object that conforms to a protocol, just use the protocol.  Swift is not like Objective-C where you need to specify `id<SomeProtocol>`:

```
public struct Subscription {
    private weak var subscriber: Subscriber? = nil
}
```

You can also declare your protocol like this if you want to restrict usage to `AnyObject`, rather than using `class`:

```
public protocol Subscriber : AnyObject {
    // ...
}
```